# Vue , no actuliza los la vista al cambiar de página

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Tengo un problema en mi web está realizada con Laravel y Vue y ocurre que muchos objetos que se pintan con Vue no cargan correctamente o se quedan como en una versión antigua y solo se actualiza recargando la página.

Ejemplo

https://autosmotos.es/results/auto?page=1&order_by=created_at%3Bdesc&items_per_page=25

Si observáis
[image]

Podeis ver la separación entre el icono y el texto tiene en css un ml-1

Pero si pasais la pagina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No ha cargado ese estilo estando en el css y si le dais a F5 pues ya aparece esto pasa en alguna partes mas del codigo pero no soy experto en VUE y no se por que puede ser.

Saludos

Comment: hola, te recomiendo leer este post https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask por otra parte, para conseguir ayuda tienes que compartir el código, ya que este problema puede tener muchas causas y compartiendo el código te podríamos dar un diagnostico.

Comment: @Ivandez entiendo, pero no puedo compartir codigo por que no se donde es el problema

Comment: Busca el controlador de Laravel y componente de vue,js que muestra esa vista. si no sabes por donde buscar, instala esta extensión de chrome Vue.js devtools la cual te dirá que componente de vue muestra esa vista.